# I have a `raspivid` stream, which I'm piping to `ffmpeg`, now i'd like to also stream a raw version of it to a socket?

Tags: socket, split, streaming, duplicate

I have a process outputing an MJPEG video stream, which I pipe into `ffmpeg` to reduce framerate and then to a socket.

```
raspivid -t 999999 -cd MJPEG -w 1920 -h 1080 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -f mjpeg -r 2 - | nc -l 9010
```

Now I need to also split the original raw stream into another socket. I've tried `tee` command, including with named fifos, but I cant seem to make it work.

Comment: try with `ffmpeg ... | tee >(nc -l other_port) | nc -l 9010`. Notice that `nc -l` is not a real server: it will exit after servicing a connection.

Comment: I've tried that, though in different order (it's the raw stream I want expose): `raspivid -t 999999 -cd MJPEG -w 1920 -h 1080 -o - | tee >(nc -l 9011) | ffmpeg -i - -f mjpeg -r 2 - | nc -l 9010` . This does seem to work for a few moment, but than stops. I'm thinking you are right in suggesting that real problem lies with the nature of `nc`, will look more into it.

Comment: Maybe that `raspivid` program doesn't handle blocking writes well, and it was only tested with "fast" outputs, like regular files or pipes connected to programs which immediately read everything from it -- like ffmpeg.

Comment: @UncleBilly Yep, I've tried it several more times and it does work from time to time, but definitely not something to rely on. I also discovered that I will need to perform additional processing on the streams, so I'll be handling splitting in code. Thanks.